# Biometric information for a UK visitor visa for the second time

Tags: visas, uk, repeat-visits

I submitted my biometric information when I applied for (and successfully received) the UK visitor visa.

Now, the visa has expired and I would like to apply for it again.

Do I need to submit my biometric information again? 
Will the process be the exact same as before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, every single application must submit the biometric and photos required each time, this prevents from anyone applying as you and committing identity theft. You will go through the same process as before in the application center, only this time at some point down the line the biometrics will be compared to the ones previously submitted to verify they are the same.

As stated by the [UK home office](https://www.emcouncils.gov.uk/write/UKBA%20Charging%20for%20Immigration%20and%20Nationality%20Services.pdf):

> Applicants for a long term visit visa benefit from the convenience of
>   not having to make multiple visa applications, **each requiring their
>   biometrics to be taken**, each time they want to come to the UK.

Comment: thanks, but I find it a bit unreasonable. They don't even have my application details saved and I have to spend an hour filling them out again :(

Comment: @joe unfortunately just another process that could be improved if they put the right resources into it, but in this case they will always value the security aspects higher than applicants convenience, and having you submit it all again just makes it harder for anyone to pretend to be you

Comment: @joe If you think that's unreasonable, the same thing applies to residence visas, which require considerably more information!